# Extract range from string

Tags: vba, excel

I have a report that exports to multiple Excel sheets.  The first row on each sheet has a similar statement to the below.

> Paste Data in range A1:K44 only.  Data to come from "History" dump in
>   Part Inquire.

I need to extract the range from that string.  I've tried to use the split and find functions, but the length of the range changes (i.e. `A1:AB53`, `A15:C20`, etc.).

I welcome any input as to how to extract the range.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use `Split()` to split your string into an array and then grab the 5th element (index = 4):

```
Const SOME_TEXT As String = "Paste Data in range A1:K44 only. Data to come from ""History"" dump in Part Inquire."

Dim strRange As String
strRange = Split(SOME_TEXT)(4)

Debug.Print strRange
```

Output:

```
A1:K44
```

If the text that appears isn't quite so consistent, you can use a regex to extract the first range that appears within your string:

```
Const SOME_TEXT As String = "This string has A1:K44 in it but is inconsistent with the rest."

Dim re
Set re = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
re.Pattern = "\b[A-Z]{1,3}\d+:[A-Z]{1,3}\d+\b"

If re.Test(SOME_TEXT) Then
    Debug.Print re.Execute(SOME_TEXT)(0)
End If
```

Comment: I would add that if the sentence has varying words (meaning the range wouldn't always be the 5th element) then use split and loop on the array, checking for a colon.

Comment: @DavidG - Thanks. I included a regex example that should work if the string isn't very consistent.

Comment: Thanks, regex is what I was trying to think of.